# Is this a correct api response?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, express

I'm trying to learn about API's and am creating a simple response when a user hit's an endpoint on my basic express app.

I'm not sure what constitutes a correct API response though, does it need to be an object?

The data I was given is an array of arrays and I export it from a file and return it in the express app as an object using response.json(), it displays ok but I'm not sure if I'm following the right approach for how I'm handling it and displaying it.

I would like to understand how should API data be returned, I had the feeling that it should always be an object but what I'm returning here is an array of arrays, some explanation to understand this better would be helpful please.

Here is my data file:

```
    export const data = [
  [
    'a9e9c933-eda2-4f45-92c0-33d6c1b495d8',
    {
      title: 'The Testaments',
      price: { currencyCode: 'GBP', amount: '10.00' },
    },
  ],
  [
    'c1e435ad-f32b-4b6d-a3d4-bb6897eaa9ce',
    {
      title: 'Half a World Away',
      price: { currencyCode: 'GBP', amount: '9.35' },
    },
  ],
  [
    '48d17256-b109-4129-9274-0bff8b2db2d2',
    { title: 'Echo Burning', price: { currencyCode: 'GBP', amount: '29.84' } },
  ],
  [
    'df2555ad-7dc2-4b1f-b422-766184b5c925',
    {
      title: ' The Institute',
      price: { currencyCode: 'GBP', amount: '10.99' },
    },
  ],
];
```

Here is a snippet from my express app file which imports the data object for this endpoint:

```
app.get('/books', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ books: data });
});
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your server so far, and  explain where you got stuck?

Comment: What you have here is not JSON if that's what your asking, .  The above result should not be whats been returned from response.json() anyway.

Comment: @Evert added a server code snippet

Comment: That extra snippet is not what's returning the above.   To me it looks like Javascript code you have exposed with serveStatic.

Comment: @Keith I'm new to learning API's, what I'm getting back from my snippet is an object which contains my data response. What I'm asking is for some clarification in what the API should be returning? Do I need to change the structure of my data array which I'm exporting?

Comment: @Keith when I hit that endpoint, I can see in network traffic that this is the response that is being returned.

Comment: Yes, but it's not the code you have shown doing it.  It's another endpoint in your express server that's sending it.   The likely culprit is serveStatic, as this will just serve out Javascript files, and that's what's been returned here, not JSON.   Maybe an idea to show us the rest of your Express routing logic..

Comment: I don't know what serveStatic is, as I said I'm new to learning about this so any explanation on this and understanding how I should structure my API arrays data would be great.

Comment: If your saying when you go to `http://mywebsite/books` and your getting the above response, you have some routing logic error in your express code, unfortunately we would need to see the rest of your express routing logic to help..

Comment: Why would I have routing logic error when that code is saying if the user goes to '/books' then show the above response and thats what it is doing? why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks okay, one thing I would do is ensure the root of the object you return always has the same name between api calls, so here your root object name is "books":

```
app.get('/books', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ books: data });
});
```

I would personally change this to something like:

```
app.get('/books', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ data: data });
});
```

Now that may seem confusing, but what that means is when your api is queried, the actual resources the api is returning is always in an object called `data`, it just builds a common pattern for where people should be expecting to see the api response resources in your JSON response.

So if you had another endpoint for authors for example, people will know the authors response will be under an object called data:

```
app.get('/authors', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ data: authors });
});
```

Comment: Thanks thats a useful point. What about the structure of the data in the data file? My aim is to understand if that is in the right format, can it be an array of arrays or does it need to be an object?

Comment: Yes an object is the standard I believe, but you are returning an object when you do `response.json({ books: data })` you are creating and returning the object `{ books: data }`

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure if the array of arrays structure though is wrong in it's format, does it need to be an object for it to be a valid json response....